# Update Xamarin ContentPage content on event isn't working

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Might be a basic question, but how do you force a page to update it's content (after it's already been loaded)?  I'm trying to dynamically update a page after a web request.  The event fires, but it doesn't seem to be refreshing the content.

```
public StartPage : ContentPage
{
    public StartPage()
    {
        var layout = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = 
            {
                new Label { Text = "Preview Page" }
            }
        };

        this.Content = layout;
    }

    //this gets called from a web service call with the text to display
    public void Update(string text)
    {
        var layout = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = 
            {
                new Label { Text = text }
            }
        };

        this.Content = layout;

        //this fires, but nothing changes
        //how can I force the page to refresh??
    }
}
```

Aplogies for the code if there are errors, doing it from memory (don't have the exact code in front of me)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should put it inside `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread()` like below

```cs
public void Update(string text)
{
  Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
  {
    var layout = new StackLayout
    {
        Children = 
        {
            new Label { Text = text }
        }
    };

    this.Content = layout;
  });
}
```

Comment: Ooof, will test when I get home.. can't believe such a silly oversight!