# Xamarin Forms-TableView - Go to First Element

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, tableview

I have in my page a TableView with different sections. The case is when I do scroll down I want that at the end there is a button to similar to scroll automatically at the top. I was thinking using Focus() or something similar, but I didn't find the correct way to do it. Is it possible to do it?

Thanks in advance.
Oscar

Comment: Why do you want that ? are you sure you want to use TableView in your case ? maybe a ListView with grouping and header and footer can do this for you ? I am asking because in ListView you can have a ScrollTo method

Comment: I have a form where the user need to fill close to 10 values, and sometimes the user need to come back to top, Is it possible in Listview this?

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: I will check it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A Xamarin.Forms.ListView with a DataTemplateSelector implementation would be the easiest way to make this work as [BraveHeart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1528563/braveheart) mentioned in his comment. But you could do this by using a custom renderer to perform this action on the native controls.

**On iOS:**
Xamarin.Forms.TableView inherits from UITableView which exposes the ScrollToRow method. In your case, you would want to call the following method in the custom renderer when this is invoked.

```
ScrollToRow(NSIndex.FromIndex(0), UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, true);
```

[Xamarin.iOS documentation on ScrollToRow method](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/UIKit.UITableView.ScrollToRow/p/Foundation.NSIndexPath/UIKit.UITableViewScrollPosition/System.Boolean/)

**On Android:**
Same idea here and you would want to invoke the following method in the Custom Renderer:

```
SmoothScrollToPosition(0,0);
```

[Xamarin.Android documentation on SmoothScrollToPosition](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Widget.AbsListView.SmoothScrollToPosition/p/System.Int32/System.Int32/)

The harder part of this is figuring out how to have the Xamarin.Forms.Button.Clicked event handler will be wired to the Platform Specific Custom Renderers. You could use the OnPropertyChanged override and use a boolean property on your Xamarin.Forms element that could be set to trigger the methods above. You could also create a custom event handler on your Xamarin.Forms.ListView and have that invoke the platform specific method. I would recommend reviewing how Xamarin.Forms does this on Android [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/ListViewRenderer.cs#L182). You could do something very similar.

I hope this help!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I never thought that this simple thing was gonna be so complicate to do in Xamarin. I would try with this and give an answer again.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the comments I would say it depends on the cases:

1. If the feilds are static and will not change (added/removed) in run time, then I would put make the fields (labels and entries) inside a [ScrollView](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ScrollView/) which has a ScrollToAsync method.
2. If the fields can be changed in run time and you do not know how many rows there will be then you use a ListView. But from what I understood you do not really need that one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tested before to put all the TableView in a ScrollView, but it is working strange maybe because the tableview has inside another ScrollView, Am I wrong?

Comment: exactly try to replace the tableView with a stacklayout or a grid

Comment: Thanks, I will try it!

Answer (score 0):

I was trying all the solutions and I have a problem different problems with all:

- Using list view: currently each cell for me is different, so I dont see the way to create a Listview with different data source.
- Scrollview: I can't use this solution because right now I need all the cells(custom ViewCell) that currently I am using.

I hope to find another solution. Thanks!

Edit: I found something interesting that works perfect for my case [Update Xamarin ContentPage content on event isn't working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28049866/update-xamarin-contentpage-content-on-event-isnt-working)

Comment: Just use the DataTemplateSelector with Forms to have a different cell. Documentation: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/templates/data-templates/selector/